# Django multiple field search form

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a query form which gets input from 3 fields and display the related matched content from the database models.
But i am trying to select only one field from the three fields on the form and need to get data from database models related to that field?

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from search.forms import ModuleForm
from django.http import HttpResponse
from search.models import Module,Metamodule,Release

def searchview(request):
     if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ModuleForm(request.GET)  
        if form.is_valid():
           release_num = form.cleaned_data['release_num']
           metamodule_name = form.cleaned_data['metamodule_name']
           module_name = form.cleaned_data['module_name']
           results =    Module.objects.filter(metamodule__release__number=release_num).filter(metamodule__name=metamodule_name).filter(name=module_name)
           return render(request,'search/search_result.html',{'form': form, 'results': results})
     else:
          form = ModuleForm()    
          return render(request, 'search/search_form.html',{'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from search.models import Module,Release,Metamodule

class ModuleForm(forms.Form):
     release_num = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Release.objects.all(),empty_label='Pick a Release')
     metamodule_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Metamodule.objects.all(),empty_label='Pick a Meta module')
     module_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Module.objects.all(),empty_label='Pick a Module')

     def clean_release_number(self):
       try:
          release_num = self.cleaned_data.get["release_num"]
          metamodule_name = int(self.cleaned_data["metamodule_name"])
          module_name = int(self.cleaned_data["module_name"])
       except:
          release_num = None
          metamodule_name = None
          module_name = None

       if release_num and    Module.objects.exclude(metamodule__release__number=release_num).exists():
           raise forms.ValidationError("Please enter a valid release number.")
       else:
           return release_num
```

How to modify the view to accept single input and display the data even though the other two fields are not provided with data?

Comment: Is the input valid if any one of the three fields has been filled in? What if two or all three fields were filled in? Should all supplied input be used?

Comment: Ya. It should support all the input filled. either one filled or more than one.It should be some if else condition needed in views i guess. Not sure how to put that logic into the views.

Answer (score 0):

Consider checking for each field and filtering on that field value individually.

```
if form.is_valid():
    release_num = form.cleaned_data['release_num']
    metamodule_name = form.cleaned_data['metamodule_name']
    module_name = form.cleaned_data['module_name']
    results = Module.objects.all()
    if release_num:
        results = results.filter(metamodule__release__number=release_num)
    if metamodule_name:
        result = results.filter(metamodule__name=metamodule_name)
    if module_name:
        result = results.filter(name=module_name)
    return render(request,'search/search_result.html',{'form': form, 'results': results})
```

It's up to you to validate the input using your `clean_fieldname()` methods. Consider using `def clean(self)` to perform multi-field validation (like having at least one field filled in).

Why are you processing your form input on `GET`? Is there a reason why you're submitting form data with `GET` and ignoring `POST`?

Also, while it's good that you're checking `form.is_valid()` and implementing `clean_fieldname` methods, you need to add an `else` clause to `if form.is_valid():` that handles `form.errors`.

Comment: I am checking the model database and getting the filtered data, So i am using GET.

Comment: I have tried the above code, But if the value is not selected in dropdown list the output is not displayed?

Comment: If you are submitting a form in a browser, the `request.method` should match the submit method in the HTML form. That was why I was asking about `GET` and `POST`. Ordinarily, `GET` should construct a new, empty form, `POST` where `form.is_valid()` handles the result filtering, and `POST` where `form.is_valid()` returns false would return the existing form object to display validation errors.

Comment: @Dave: Ya. I am submitting the form with GET and the submit button in html form also is 'GET'. The if conditions are not working for me. How to get matching data for only one field and not selecting other fields in form?

Comment: If the `if release_num:`, etc. statements aren't working, you may have a problem getting data from the HTTP GET request to the form. Consider printing the `request.GET` and `form.cleaned_data` dictionaries to see if the form input is arriving in a manner you expect.